# How to get the Pricing tier of an analysis service using azure AzAnalysisServicesServer powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, ssas

I am using Azure Module 'Get-AzAnalysisServicesServer' to get the Analysis services Pricing Tier.

I am not able to get the Pricing Tier. Eg "S1".

Comment: I thought the Sku property of the output would tell you S1. Can you post the output you are seeing? It should match the docs which say the following is returned: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.analysisservices.models.azureanalysisservicesserver?view=azurerm-ps

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, the pricing tier will be included in the `Sku`, just use the command as below.

```
(Get-AzAnalysisServicesServer -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <Analysis Service Name>).Sku
```

[image]

Comment: @Ranix Hi, if it is helpful, could you accept it as the answer?https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work